# Table Not Populating as I expected using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to populate a table using a JSON file. When I run this through the browser, my first row populates. However the other rows do not. Can someone please point out to me what I am doing wrong? Am I not looping this correctly? Thank you in advance.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$.getJSON( "data.json", function(data) {
  var htmlToRender= [];
    var item;
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {  
      item = data[i];
      console.log(data[i]);
      htmlToRender = '<tr><td>' + item.name + '</td>'
                     '<td>' + item.description + '</td>'
                     console.log(item.description)
                     '<td><a href="https://www.google.com/maps?q=' + item.location + '">Open In Google Mapspwd</a></td></tr>';
                     console.log(item.location);
                     $('#hot-spots').append(htmlToRender);
                     console.log(htmlToRender);
             };
         });
     });
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you post your JSON data and output so we know what we're working with? Having said that, your semicolon/ `+` string-building situation appears fragile. Your `item.description` line is probably not doing what you expect (there's no `+` to join it with the previous line).

Comment: Oh my gosh, thank you ggorlen, you're a life saver. It was the +'s, ha.

Answer (score 0):

The lines following `htmlToRender = '<tr><td>' + item.name + '</td>'` look a bit suspicious--you're missing a `+` sign to concatenate these additional strings, and sprinkled `console.log`s amidst the string build isn't helping the cause.

I recommend using a string template:

```js
const item = {
  name: "hello",
  description: "world",
  location: "somewhere"
};

const htmlToRender = `
  <tr>
    <td>${item.name}</td>
    <td>${item.description}</td>
    <td>
      <a href="https://www.google.com/maps?q=${item.location}">Open In Google Maps</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
`;
$('#hot-spots').append(htmlToRender);
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="hot-spots"></table>
```

Comment: I like this solution, it ran an error at the end when I tried it though. Said unexpected input on the append to # hot-spots line..

Comment: Hmm, I think I'd have to see your code to debug that. Without a complete/verifiable example I can't produce a verifiable answer. Could you post a link to a repl or fiddle?